# SSRS Aggregating Aggregates

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have been banging my head against a wall for the better part of two days now...

My scenario is this:

I have a recordset I have divvied up into 4 groups in an SSRS table.  They are:

```
StartPeriod 
  --> Area
     --> Job#
        --> Details
```

The column in question is one that contains two different record counts. One is the # of records with an error, and the other is the total number of records for this group (so that I can run a percentage).

For example:

At the details level I might have an item with 4 errors, and an item with 6 and there are a total of 20 records.  This means that the total # of records is repeating, which means I cannot sum this number or I will double count my total # of records.

```
StartPeriod - Area - Job# - Item  - Errors - totalRecords
 January    - 123  - Job3 - item1 -   4    -     20
 January    - 123  - Job3 - item2 -   6    -     20
```

I can get around this at the Job# level because I can simply say Max(num_records) to get the correct number....however if I want to aggregate up to the Area level (or above) I can't get things to work.  I can't do SUM( Max(num_records) ) because that makes no sense, and however I arrange the query in SQL it doesn't add up either.

I feel like this is a fairly common problem, so I am not sure why I am having so much trouble.  Any ideas how I can solve this?  I hope I am explaining myself clearly.

PS. I am using SSRS 2008R2

Answer (score 2):

Make better use of groups, the data already exists in your query.

```
CountRows("Details")
Sum(Errors, "Details")
```

This is assuming the group you've created at the details level is called "Details".

Comment: The problem I get with this is that as I go up the hierarchy this doesn't work.  I get an error saying "The value expression has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function"

Comment: At each group level you would need to substitute "Details" for the appropriate group or "scope" as it is called in SSRS.  At the top of the hierarchy you would want to use the scope-less overloads, that would simply be to remove the scope parameter entirely: CountRows() and Sum(Errors).

Comment: That gets me as far as up to the job# level correctly...however, now I want to add the numbers I've arrived at together.  For example: Job1 has the correct total of 20, Job2 has the correct total of 30, so now when I collapse the 'Area' group, I need to see a total of '50'.  Instead I see an average being continued...

Comment: To clarify further, my record count fields are calculated prior to entering into SSRS because they are based on several factors / different tables.  I am adding not a count() in SSRS but these calculated numbers.

Comment: In my own mock up of your problem I am able to Sum at each different scope level (group) and it works just fine. Using SSRS expressions and assuming the names of your groups: on the Job# Level **Sum(Fields!Errors.Value, "Job#")**, on the Area level **Sum(Fields!Errors.Value, "Area")**, on the StartPeriod level **Sum(Fields!Errors.Value, "StartPeriod")**

Comment: Maybe this will help.  here is a cleansed partial example of my data: http://sharesend.com/mkptckw1

Comment: Basically,the second column of numbers is the total # of records for that job#, and the errors column is the number of errors for that item in that job.  So when I collapse to the job level I want that second column number (which might be repeating) to divide the sum of the first column.  However, after the job level (area, period etc) I want to sum the total # across jobs.  So for job24, the number 7 should be factored in only once when you collapse to the area level.

Comment: Is there any way you could show the output using and indicate what is wrong about it?  I'm really not following you.  If you want the different levels to display different aggregations, you need to use different expressions at those different levels.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for your query:

```
declare @totcount int
select @totcount = sum(errors) from your_table
select errors, errors/@totcount as [% of total] from your_table
```

as for the area:

```
declare @totcount int
select @totcount = sum(errors) from your_table
select area, sum(errors)/@totcount as [% of total] 
from your_table 
group by area
```

Comment: I've tried this before, an that gets me to the point where I can get the numbers right per job, but once I collapse that group and look at an aggregation on area....the numbers don't add up

Comment: If you're trying to aggregate aggregate ratios, forget it, bad medicine. Look at the second example I added.

Comment: I don't want to aggregate ratios, my problem is that the 'total' number I have is not exclusive at the lowest level of my grouping.  Because of that I have to eliminate the aggregation of that field at the 'job' level, then sum it after that.  Sorry I know that is probably fairly confusing...but I'm not sure of a better way to word it.